# SQL string group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table which contains `name` `surname` and some other attributes, which are not important. The table has over a million rows so there is many names or surnames that are same - duplicates.

What I want to do is create a histogram, which will return every `name` in the table with a number of occurences. Same for every other attribute in my table.

I have tried to write a simple select like this, which returns a number (occurences) of name `Aaron` in the table:

```
select count(name)
from public.customers 
where name = 'Aaron'
```

But problem is that I would have to have a list of all names that are in the table and then write for each name one select, which is not very smart. It would take a lot of time of course. Isn't there a better and easier way to do it?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `group by` with aggregation function `count`:

```
select name,
    count(*) as occurrences
from public.customers
group by name
order by name;
```

#### EDIT:

If you want to get count of occurrences, you can do double aggregation:

```
select occurrences,
    count(*) as count_of_occurrence
from (
    select name,
        count(*) as occurrences
    from public.customers
    group by name
    ) t
group by occurrences
order by count_of_occurrence;
```

Comment: and what if I want to get the occurence in reversed way? I mean I want to print out not the occurence of name `Aaron` but I want to print out how many occurencies is in the table that have occurence for example `35` .

Comment: @Ady96 - Please see the updated answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Btw, what is the `t` ? And also, If I want to order it by the occurence, where do I add `order by`?

Comment: @Ady96 - `t` is alias for the subquery.

Comment: I updated my comment, regarding ordering the occurrence.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `count_of_occurrence`.

Comment: @Ady96 - Updated again. Just a matter of change what to order by

Comment: That 's why I ask so simple question because this doesn't work.

Comment: @Ady96 - doesnt work how? does it give you an error?

Comment: Yes, `column count_of_occurrence does not exist`

Comment: Oh never mind, it was only a typo, I had an `s` at the end `count_of_occurrence+s` :D thanks man, all good :)

Comment: @Ady96 - Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple example of a `group by` query:

```
select name, count(*)
from customers
group by name
order by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select name, Count(*)
 from public.customers
 group by name
```